# Can Delegates cause memory leaks?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, delegates

Can Delegates cause memory leaks?

I mean, by e.g. if a class `A` contains a `ADelegate` and the latter points to the `BMethod` (of `B` class) can this prevent the A class or B class collection by the GC?

If so, how can we "free" delegates (setting `ADeletate = Nothing` / null?)

How do you comment this one:

```
//Class A Finalize, containing ADelegateInstance as ADelegate'
protected override void Finalize()
{
    ADelegateInstance = 
        (ADelegate)System.Delegate.RemoveAll(
            ADelegateInstance, ADelegateInstance);
    ADelegateInstance = null;
    base.Finalize();
}

'Class A Finalize, containing ADelegateInstance as ADelegate'
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    ADelegateInstance = _ 
        CType(System.Delegate.RemoveAll(ADelegateInstance, ADelegateInstance), _ 
            ADelegate)
    ADelegateInstance = Nothing
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the reference will stay alive unless you unsubscribe from the event:

```
someObject.SomeEvent -= SomeDelegate;
```

Comment: what if I have a big complex object with multiple delegates subscriptions/unsubscriptions, finally in the Dispose of this object I want to "let die" all links to this delegate.

Comment: Then you can implement IDisposable.

Comment: yes, and what should I write in the Dispose method for that delegate. , maybe `System.Delegate.RemoveAll(myDelegate, myDelegate)` would help?

Comment: You would do just as I have sown in my example.

Comment: @serhio: Syntax was hardly the focus of the question.  The concept is the same.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the context that a closure/delegates refers to can indeed not be garbage collected as long as the closure/delegate is still referenced -- otherwise it would lose its context.

Taking the example for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226510/closures-in-c-event-handler-delegates/2226529#2226529), we see that a delegate can reference the variable `inneri` in the context of the object. So the object which actually holds `inneri` can not be garbage collected until the delegate is no more referenced, in this case, until the `Button` has been garbage collected.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    var inneri = i;
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Text = "Click me!";
    newButton.Click += delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am button number " + inneri);
    };
    this.Controls.Add(newButton);
}
```

Related posts:

- [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-captured-variable-in-loop)
- [Closures in C# event handler delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226510/closures-in-c-event-handler-delegates/2226529#2226529)
- [What are 'closures' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)

Comment: in other words, you mean that B will not be collected as long as ADelegate points to it?..

Answer (score 2):

Just having a reference is not enough to cause a memory leak.  Consider the following.

If a thread spawns 3 objects (where -> denotes a reference), A -> B -> C -> A

If A is not referenced by the thread, all are collected.  Circular references are dealt with by the GC.

However, this also obviously means, if a delegate contains a reference to an object, and that object with the delegate is still referenced, then the delegate function will not be cleaned up.

That would give you the following below.

A - (object with delegate)
B - object containing a function reference.

When A falls out of scope, then B will to.

Answer (score 1):

If A contains a delegate to a function in B then A will not be destroyed by the GC.

It's a good idea to always put in a "mydelegate -= B.method" everytime you write a "mydelegate += B.method".

Although it's not a real memory leak as the objects can still be reached.

Answer (score 0):

There was a situation when in ASP.NET application a singleton was used. And for some reason it used to subscribe to events of controls. The fact that it was a singleton (containing reference to itself) did not allow GC to collect it, on the other hand that singleton have never removed subscriptions to control events. That caused a permanent growth of memory consumption: controls used to serve a single request where not cleaned by GC due to existing reference from the singleton, new controls where created for each new request.